# timeout with IOS app from Visual Studio (xamarin)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm on the latest stable version of xamarin on both pc and mac. I'm trying to build the hello world app from VS but I get trouble.

In fact, Visual Studio launch the simulator on the mac, but nothing is runing on the simulator (black screen).

I finally get an error-messgae dur to the timeout.

Thanks to any idea to resolve that problem :-)

Comment: does this work when using xamarin studio from mac?

Comment: @Sten Petrov : No, the simulator is closing!

Comment: I'd try reinstalling xcode, seems like it's an issue with the simulator itself. Try resetting the simulator image too.

Comment: Is the simulator closing or is your app closing? When debugging on the mac, is anything printed in Xamarin Studio's console?

Comment: @StenPetrov : I've re-installed the xcode & I very quickly go to Simulator > restart settings or something like that just before the crash to renew the config. All is ok with XCode app but I didn't see the Target IOS devices from VisualStudio (and the mac is ok) sn I can't try to build

Comment: The "Reinitialiser les contenus et les reglages" button should be "re-initialize content and settings" in english ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came back to explain the resolution of my problem.

I followed the steps mentionned here : [enter link description here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/6084/#Comment_6084)  but I really think that the main problem was the fact that the application had'nt the application name the identifier and the version, so go to the project in VS and edit it : (http://screencast.com/t/jM7LGcY5yp)

Comment: Specifically, adding name, identifier and a version solved this problem for me.