# Connection error when connecting to my mac from visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, broker, remote-login

For me all I do is open `Visual Studio`, click on connect to Mac, and then I get this error message:

> The Broker initialization exceeded the timeout of 60000 millisecs
>   without receiving confirmation from the Broker.

I have tried restarting my Mac and PC and creating a new project. I have the latest versions of VS installed on both my Mac and PC. This issue is really annoying so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by connecting to your Mac from Visual Studio.

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881391/timeout-with-ios-app-from-visual-studio-xamarin

Comment: @RobL I mean when I try to connect to my mac I get this error message

Comment: @subdeveloper I already tried those steps and that is a different problem from what I am having

Comment: @ChristianBadenhausen as Rob L suggested, can you please update the question with more details of the workflow you are doing. Please use **exact** names of buttons/menu items you are clicking. Also if confidentiality is not an issue provide a **full** screenshot.